# android google maps animation between 2 locations, advice

Tags: android, google-maps, animation

Hi I have created a map as well as some markers which indicate places/locations on the map. Is there any possible way of creating an animation between those location? For instance drawing a polyline between 2 different locations and create an animation from a start point to an end point ? Is there any documentation for such a thing or any tutorials ? Many thanks.

Something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPWYorS68WE

Comment: By following the link in the "About" section of that video, there was an in depth tutorial on how to achieve the animation you are after. Google provides an animateCamera call and the animation between markers is done via linear interpolation which is explained in the tutorial link.

Comment: Hey thank you I will just have a look now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code and you can also follow this link
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/
Flat Markers
 LatLng mapCenter = new LatLng(41.889, -87.622);

```
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mapCenter, 13));

    // Flat markers will rotate when the map is rotated,
    // and change perspective when the map is tilted.
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.direction_arrow))
            .position(mapCenter)
            .flat(true)
            .rotation(245));

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder()
            .target(mapCenter)
            .zoom(13)
            .bearing(90)
            .build();

    // Animate the change in camera view over 2 seconds
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition),
            2000, null);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks but if I run the code the only thing that happens is that a marker is generated on the map more specifically a flat marker. there is no animation or so.

Comment: OK I see now I had a few mistakes but If I want to add another location and animate the camera on the first location and then on the second location what can i do for that ?